# Apple Push Notification is not working on my godaddy shared server, it's throght failed to connect 111 connection refused php push notification error

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I got a error like failed to connect 111 connection refused php push    notification using APNS.
It's working fine on local server but not working on GoDaddy shared server.Please find my Php code.

```
$path_pem_file="http://dummy.com/uploads/app/1.pem";
// this is the pass phrase you defined when creating the key
$passphrase = '';
// this is where you can customize your notification
$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"message","sound":"default"}}';

// start to create connection
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $path_pem_file);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,   $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', 'Device token here..') . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if ($fp) {  fclose($fp);}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have following PORTs open on your server to use Apple APNs

```
2195
2196
```

As far as I know GoDaddy will not open this ports for you on shared hosting and you will have to go for Dedicated server or VPS.

Comment: You are right GoDaddy is not allow to not open this ports in shared hosting. I have talk with GoDaddy support

Comment: So there is no other option except using dedicated server for sending iOS push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **GoDaddy** Web Hosting, they will not open the ports to send push. If you are using GoDaddy Virtual Private Servers, then you can call them and get the ports unlocked.

**You need to go for Dedicated Hosting**.
Please have a look on the following url, this may help you :
http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=b580c417cbbc86eb9575ea0&currentpage=1